# Seaside: Ajax callback, then append server-rendered element?

Tags: ajax, smalltalk, seaside

My goal is to create a menu item (a span) which, when clicked, does
three things. First, it sets some state on the server (addTurn), then
it creates a new element (renderEmptyTurnOn) on the server and sends
it to the client. Then the client, having received the new element,
appends it to a specific element with class #zdTurns. I only want one
server roundtrip.

The code below fails because renderEmptyTurnOn is expecting a canvas,
but I am passing it a script instead.

Is there an idiomatic way to do this using vanilla seaside and
jquery?

```
renderMenuOn: h
    h div
        class: 'zdDialogMenu';
        with: [ 
                    h span
                        onClick:
                                (h jQuery ajax
                                        callback: [ self dialog addTurn ];
                                        script: [ :s | s << ((s jQuery class: #zdTurns) append: (s jQuery html: (self renderEmptyTurnOn: s))) ]);
                        with: 'Add Turn' ]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You almost nailed it. The argument of an `append:` message on a jQuery instance accepts a renderable object. This could be a string, a Seaside component or a block. That means you can do it as follows:

```
renderMenuOn: h
  h div
    class: 'zdDialogMenu';
    with: [ 
       h span
          onClick: (h jQuery ajax
                        script: [ :s | 
                                 self dialog addTurn.
                                 s << ((s jQuery class: 'zdTurns') append: [:r | self renderEmptyTurnOn: r ]) ]);
          with: 'Add Turn' ]
```

Comment: Ah, thanks! And this is only one server round trip because the callback: is primary and the script: is secondary?

Comment: Oops, no it's not correct. `callback:` registers a primary callback and `script:` as well, so they cannot be combined. Instead, use `callback:value:` and `script:`, or just `script:`. I know it's a bit silly but that's how it currently is. I have adapted the example above to make it work.